# How can I find the radius and interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(3x-2)^n \over n} $, and for what value x would it converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(3x-2)^n \over n} $$

Not sure where to start with this problem. I'm thinking the ratio test because the numerator is raised to n, but n is also in the denominator.

Comment: The ratio test is a good start! Instead of thinking numerator/denominator, think $a_n=(3x-2)^n/n$.

Comment: Make $3x-2=y$. Now, it looks quite familiar, no ?

Answer (score 1):

by using the ratio test 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3x-2)^{n+1}}{n+1}*\frac{n}{(3x-2)^n}=\frac{n}{n+1}(3x-2)=\frac{3x-2}{1+1/n}$$

when the $n\rightarrow \infty $
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=3x-2$$
if the series converge,   $$|(3x-2)|<1$$

Comment: So basically I'm attempting to solve the problem down until 'n' is gone, and then I can say that if it's convergent, |something|<1. But do I need to solve for x to say what it will converge to? Or is that not something one can know?

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition for a series to be convergent is that its terms have to be infinitesimal, so we need $|3x-2|\leq 1$ or $x\in\left[\frac{1}{3},1\right]$. $x=1$ leads to the harmonic series that is divergent, while the left endpoint $x=\frac{1}{3}$ leads to a series that is convergent by Leibniz' criterion. To finish, we just need to recall that, by the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$ in a neighbourhood of $x=0$,

$$\forall x\in\left[\frac{1}{3},1\right),\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(3x-2)^n}{n}=\log(3-3x).$$

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test is often a good choice when n is both inside of an exponent [not including (-1)^n] and outside of an exponent.

In other words, it's not a problem that n is outside of an exponent in your denominator here; rather, it's part of what makes the ratio test a good match.

When n is only inside an exponent, but not outside of an exponent, then you usually have a geometric series, and the ratio test is not needed.  For instance, if your nth term was just (3x - 1)^n with no denominator, then you would have a geometric series with r = 3x - 1, and you would solve |r| < 1 without resorting to the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=(3x-2)$. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(3x-2)^n \over n} $$ Now,the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty {z^n \over n} $ is $\displaystyle {1 \over \limsup_{n \to \infty} ({1 \over n})^{1 \over n}}=1$.

The series is convergent for $|z|<1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$ i.e when $\displaystyle |3x-2|<1$, it converges.When $z=1$, it does not converge but converges for $z=-1$.